# ASP.NET Core project upgraded from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017RC throws an error on every start.

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded an ASP.NET Core project from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017RC, and now every time I run the new project, before `Program.Main` gets hit, a dialog is shown:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Once that has been OK'ed Visual Studio continues and `Program.Main` is called.

This only happens when running the project directly, running IISExpress appears to avoid the issue.

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the upgrade tools for Visual Studio 2017. The problem is in `Properties/launchSettings.json` - the format has changed but the upgrade doesn't handle them.

In Visual Studio 2015:

```
"MyApplication": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "http://localhost:12345/home",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

In Visual Studio 2017 this needs to become:

```
"MyApplication": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "home",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12345"
}
```

Adding that `"applicationUrl"` property fixes the exception pop-up.